# Change scale of axes in octave plot

Tags: plot, octave, scale, octave-gui

I am using the `plot` function of [octave](/questions/tagged/octave) to plot a graph. The code is as below -

```
plot([1; 2; 3; 4], [1; 2; 3; 4]);
```

The graph looks as below -
[image]

As you can see, the plot is using a scale of 1.5 on both x and y axes. I want to change the scale to 1 on both axes. How can I do this?

Comment: are you talking about the 'tick' marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xticks` and `yticks` commands to set the ticks to what you prefer. E.g.

```
xticks( 1:4 )
yticks( 1:4 )
```